# dynamically removing textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox

I am dynamically adding and removing textboxes though I can successfully adds textbox but unable to remove textbox on clicking the remove button every time i have to reload the browser to remove the textboxes after clicking remove button.

here is my javascript for adding and removing textboxes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
   var COUNTER = 3;
   var labelArray = ["answer", "rank"];

   $("#addButton").click(function () {
       for(var i = 0; i < labelArray.length; i++){
        createNewInput(labelArray[i]);
    }
     COUNTER++;
    });


function createNewInput(label){
    var tbDiv = $('#TextBoxesGroup');
    var str = '<div class="control-group">';
    str += '<label class="control-label">' + label + " " + COUNTER + '</label>';
    str += '<div class="controls">';
    str += '<input type="text" id="' + label + '_' + COUNTER + '" name="'+ label +'_' + COUNTER + '" />';
    str += '</div>';
    str += '</div>';
    tbDiv.append(str);
};


  $("#removeButton").click(function () {
             if(COUNTER==3){
               alert("No more textbox to remove");
               return false;
           }   
               COUNTER--;
              $("#TextBoxesGroup" +COUNTER).remove();
        });
  });
  </script>
```

here is my html for textboxes.

```
<div id="TextBoxesGroup">
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">answer_1: </label>
    <div class="controls"> 
        <input type="text"  name="answer_1"  id="answer_1" required="true" >
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
       <label class="control-label" for="rank1">Rank 1</label>
       <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" name="rank_1" id="rank_1" required="true">
    </div>
     </div>


    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">answer_2: </label>
    <div class="controls"> 
       <input type="text"  name="answer_2"  id="answer_2" required="true" >
        <button class="btn btn-mini btn-danger" data-toggle="button" type="button" id="removeButton">
                              -
        </button>
         <button class="btn btn-mini btn-success" data-toggle="button" type="button" id="addButton">
                               +
      </button>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
             <label class="control-label" for="rank1" required="true">Rank 2</label>
              <div class="controls">
          <input type="text" name="rank_2" id="rank_2" required="true">
         </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

can anyone what's wrong in it so that I am unable to remove textboxes on clicking the button ? Thanks

Comment: Rather than simply pasting code, its better to create a fiidle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to modify 2 things here:

1- when appending the new elements, mark their holding div with the current COUNTER value at the end, so it's easy to target them later (like on step 2 below).

so adding new elements should be like this:

```
function createNewInput(label){
            var tbDiv = $('#TextBoxesGroup');
            var str = '<div class="control-group'+COUNTER+'">';
            str += '<label class="control-label">' + label + " " + COUNTER + '</label>';
    ...
    ...
```

instead of this:

```
function createNewInput(label){
                    var tbDiv = $('#TextBoxesGroup');
                    var str = '<div class="control-group">';
                    str += '<label class="control-label">' + label + " " + COUNTER + '</label>';
```

2- when removing elements, we will target those with the current COUNTER value at the end of their class name,this way you will remove the last group, and still check if the groups are 3 or lower, no removal should happen.

```
$("#removeButton").click(function () {
                         if(COUNTER==3){
                           alert("No more textbox to remove");
                           return false;
                       }   
                   COUNTER--; 
                  $(".control-group"+COUNTER).remove();

                    });
              });
```

**Update:** check my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/qqqyC/1/

**note:** considering that we are appending the COUNTER value at the end of the `class` name. if class is giving you any styles it will not work. in this case you should not use class name as the target property and consider marking the new group using another attribute/property, and target this attribute/property when removing your elements.

Comment: I've found a small bug, i'm considering to edit the fiddle to be working, hold on :)

Comment: it must remove both fields answer and rank. it is removing only removing rank.

Comment: I've updated my fiddle, please check my updated answer above.

Comment: Thanks for your response, here still i need to reload the page.

Comment: please check my updated fiddle, you may have clicked on the old one, I've updated it from a few minutes. if it's not working, let me know what is the part that is not working in specific.

Comment: as you said above yes, that class is giving style might be that's what it is not working.

Comment: @waseem: glade that you have found your answer, but consider that mine is working and has been posted before your accepted answer, but anyway glade that I could help you :)

Comment: Oh yeah, your answer working fine... going to mark it yours as you answered first.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as you want to bind `$("#removeButton").click(function () {` to dynamically added elements.   It should be

```
$("#removeButton").on("click", function () {
  //.....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
               var COUNTER = 3;
               var labelArray = ["answer", "rank"];

               $("#addButton").click(function () {
                   for(var i = 0; i < labelArray.length; i++){
                    createNewInput(labelArray[i]);
                }
                 COUNTER++;
                });


            function createNewInput(label){
                var tbDiv = $('#TextBoxesGroup');
                var str = '<div class="control-group">';
                str += '<label class="control-label">' + label + " " + COUNTER + '</label>';
                str += '<div class="controls">';
                str += '<input type="text" id="' + label + '_' + COUNTER + '" name="'+ label +'_' + COUNTER + '" />';
                str += '</div>';
                str += '</div>';
                tbDiv.append(str);
            };


              $("#removeButton").click(function () {

                         if(COUNTER==3){
                           alert("No more textbox to remove");
                           return false;
                       }   
                           COUNTER--;
               $("#answer_" +COUNTER).parent('div').parent('div').remove();
               $("#rank_" +COUNTER).parent('div').parent('div').remove();
                    });
              });
```

Please update script or check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Cne2Q/

Answer (score 0):

```
                  $("#removeButton").click(function () {
                         if(COUNTER==3){
                           alert("No more textbox to remove");
                           return false;
                       }   
                           COUNTER--;
                          $("#TextBoxesGroup" +COUNTER).remove();
                    });
```

What you're doing here, - you're trying to remove an element like `$("#TextBoxesGroup1")` which obviously doesn't exist. So what you need to do is modify your create new input like this:

```
            function createNewInput(label){
                var tbDiv = $('#TextBoxesGroup');
                var str = '<div id="textBoxContainer'+COUNTER+'" class="control-group">';
                str += '<label class="control-label">' + label + " " + COUNTER + '</label>';
                str += '<div class="controls">';
                str += '<input type="text" id="' + label + '_' + COUNTER + '" name="'+ label +'_' + COUNTER + '" />';
                str += '</div>';
                str += '</div>';
                tbDiv.append(str);
            };
```

and your remove button

```
                  $("#removeButton").click(function () {
                         if(COUNTER==3){
                           alert("No more textbox to remove");
                           return false;
                       }   
                           COUNTER--;
                          $("#textBoxContainer" +COUNTER).remove();
                    });
```